# Blender Internal's fire simulation has different result in actual render than viewport

Tags: materials

[image]

Using "Quick Smoke" on a starting cube and turn on "Smoke+Fire" in the flow object gives this result. Why can something in the viewport (Material View) has a kind of additive effect while not in the real render?

The render layer have almost everything included from the start. I don't understand what it is excluding.